# Bluetooth Explorer removed from Xcode Tools in 12.x?

Tags: hardware, xcode, bluetooth

Apple's [Additonal Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=additional) package includes a great set of tools that are useful even for non-developers. One of these  is **Bluetooth Explorer**, which, among other things, can help enable the hidden higher-quality AptX audio codec for paired devices.

I noticed this tool is now absent from the 12.0 disk image. `Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_11.4.dmg` contains the tool, but `Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_12.dmg` does not.

Anyone know if this means it's gone for good?

[image: screenshot of the BT Explorer app]

Comment: This is basically a yes / no question (which is fine) but if there is a specific task you seek (like documenting that codec switch option’ please @ me in comments if you link to or ask  a new question. It would be fun to figure if we can still accomplish some specific tasks in 11 and / or on Apple Silicon.

Answer (score 7):

Not only it's been removed, I've tried to use the Bluetooth Explorer for Xcode 11.4 and it's not functional.

Comment: The Bluetooth Explorer from 11.4 is working for me on Catalina, tho I did have to run it twice - it is however barely readable in dark mode.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in MacOS 14.4, crashes going into audio options.